# send a facebook message to user by js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, chatbot

I'm trying to create a chat-bot that sends information to friends, after they visited my site.  (and approved the chat-bot app)
I've inserted the JavaScript FB SDK - so that i can get the FB id.

The JS code in my site:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '************',
             version    : 'v2.8',
       status: false,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    var fbID  = response.authResponse.userID;
    }
    else
    {
        //login...
    }
    });
```

**but - the userID i'm getting - doesn't exist when the bot is trying to send a message to it.**

The error I'm getting on the bot's server side:

```
Error:  { message: '(#100) No matching user found',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 100,
  error_subcode: 2018001,
  fbtrace_id: 'DHDOd3pYAFV' }
```

**now, i know that Facebook has a policy to keep the id's different - but this is the SAME APP!**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe there is an "app scoped id" and a specific "bot scoped id"? i did not compare them so far, but if you get different user ids per app then that´s most likely the case. just check out the id you get when the user writes something to the bot.

Comment: Messenger bot user ids are page-scoped. You are _not supposed_ to just get ids from elsewhere, and use them in your bot. Messenger bots are a platform for communication between a single user and a page; trying to built a chat between users based on it is not allowed.

Comment: 1. i've got the user id from the bot - it is a different. 
i'm searching for getting the app scope id from the user id itself.

2. the conversation is between the user and a designated page - but i want to create a connection between that FB user to the site it self.